# how to convert JSON timestamp into date in java?

Tags: java, json, timestamp

Hi I have a JSON object which has a "TimeStamp" filed as below

```
"timestamp":1602830127
```

Now I want to compare this time stamp is less than 3 minutes from my current time.
How can I do this in Java?
And also I need to convert this into `ZonedDateTime` format as well

I tried something like this because then I can get it as a long number

```
long timestamp2 = 1602830127;
    
   
     
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        timestamp2 = timestamp2 + 10;
        acceptEvent(new Event(new Timestamp(timestamp2).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()), UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        //acceptEvent(new Event(ZonedDateTime.now().minusSeconds(i), UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
    }
```

But it always returns a wrong  as
1970-01-19T18:43:50.137+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
How can I achive these 2? Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: `new Timestamp(timestamp)` is using ms. You need to multiply seconds by 1000, `timestamp2 *= 1000;`. (and `timestamp2 = timestamp2 + 10000;` too)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Stick to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: This avoids the outdated class *and* fixes the problem you are asking about:`Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp2).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. In  my time zone the times now start from 2020-10-16T08:35:27+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen].

Comment: I don’t think the linked original questions answer everything you’re asking. You are also asking a lot, there’s more than one question in your question. It’s probably better to ask them as separate questions.